# Question from ISI, previous years

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $n$ be a positive integer and $\phi: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{n}$ be the homomorphism defined by $\phi(1)=(n, \overline{1})$, where $\overline{1}$ denotes the set of integers congruent to $1 \bmod n$. Prove that $\left(\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{n}\right) / \operatorname{Im}(\phi)$ is cyclic and find its order.

My approach:

$\phi(1)=(n, 1) \subseteq \mathbb Z \oplus\mathbb Z_{n}$ and

I think

im $\phi(n)=(n z \oplus 1)$

I cannot argue from here please help..

Comment: Think about the projection maps of $\phi$ given by $\phi_1 : \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z, \phi_1(1) = n$ and $\phi_2 : \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z_n, \phi_2(1) = \bar{1}$. You can describe these maps. What is their nature? (Image, order of image, is the quotient by image cyclic etc.) and use that information to go back to $\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z_n$.

Comment: To do this more systematically (or algorithmically), note that the quotient group in question isisomorphic to ${\mathbb Z}^2/N$, where $N = \langle (n,1),(0,n) \rangle$, which can be solved by the Smith Normal Form algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is obvious that $\mathrm{Im}(\phi)=\left<(n,\bar 1)\right>$. Now let's define a map $\psi:\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z_n\to\mathbb Z_{n^2}$ by $\psi(a,\bar b)=\widehat{a-nb}$. Prove that $\psi$ is well defined, is a surjective group homomorphism, and $\ker\psi=\left<(n,\bar 1)\right>$. Then use the fundamental isomorphism theorem for groups.

Comment: What  is the  meaning  of $\widehat{a-nb}?$ widehat mean ?

Comment: What else than the residue class of $a-nb$ modulo $n^2$?